# Replace contents between quotes

Tags: regex, powershell

Trying to strip out values between double quotes (something similar to: https://regex101.com/r/nswcpL/3/). I am using this to find the values:

```
$pat = "/([`"])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1/g"
```

But when I run

```
[regex]::Replace($file1, $pat, " ") | Out-File $dest
```

it is looking for an exact match of the pattern (sorry not sure how to word this). What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: "*What am I missing/ doing wrong?*" - parsing XML with regex? Use ConvertFrom-XML ? In fact, why are you doing this at all, just write the template with no data and echo it N times?

Comment: Try `$file -replace "([\`"])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1", '""'` instead; you have to get rid of the `//g` part and just keep the pattern, PowerShell/.Net regex engine doesn't use that.

Comment: ^ ah man thank you so much :D. I need it to compare multiple sets of files with unknown structures for a one off task. Figured regex would be faster.

Comment: The pattern should look like `$pat = '([\`"])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1'` I think.